# Why Japanese cherry trees blossom so early in spring?

Tags: evolution, botany, flowers

My understanding is that flowers' main benefit are the insects which attracted to the shape/taste of these and facilitate cross pollination. Yet the Japanese cherry trees start (and end) to blossom (in my observation) way before the most of insects become active. What is the evolutionary explanation for such a behavior?

Comment: Might be good to read [Austen and Weis 2015](http://onlinelibrary.wiley.com/doi/10.1111/evo.12709/abstract)

Comment: Perhaps your assumption about insect activity is wrong?  We're just now getting early spring flowers (crocus, snowdrops, &c), and bees (or something bee-like) are busy pollinating them.

Comment: Well in Tokyo now it's just above 10C during the days, and it's half of that in the nights. Yet the local 梅 (ume) trees already have bloomed and now are naked again - the leafs will appear in another 3 weeks I guess. I don't think I could spot any insects so far.